If $G$ is a simply connected Lie group and $H^2 (\mathfrak{g};\mathbb{R})=0$, then $H^2 (G;\mathbb{R})=0$?
Let $G$ be a connected Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ its Lie algebra.
My question is that: If $G$ is a simply connected and $H^2 (\mathfrak{g};\mathbb{R})=0$, then  $H^2 (G;\mathbb{R})=0$?
My question is related to the Bargmann's theorem: Let $G$ be a connected and simply connected Lie group with $H^2 (\mathfrak{g};\mathbb{R})=0$. Then any projective representation admits a lifitng which is a representation. We know that any any projective representation $T:G\to U(H)$ of a Lie group $G$ in a Hilbert space $H$ leads to a real 2-cocycle $C:G\times G\to \mathbb{R}$. If $C$ is trivial, then it can be absorbed by degining $\tilde{T}(g)=e^{ik(g)}T(g)$ which is a representation in which $C(f,g)=K(fg)-K(f)-K(g)$.

Doesn't this just follow from the fact that $\pi_2 G = 0$ (and Hurewicz's theorem, noting that $\pi_1 G = 0$)?

@anomaly Could you please explain it to me a little bit more? I don't know much about $\pi_2$ and Hurewicz's theorem .

@anomaly I think the OP is asking about (continuous) group cohomology, not singular (or an equivalent) cohomology.

@LukasHeger: Ah, I thought $H^2(G, \mathbb{R})$ was the de Rham cohomology of $G$ (as a topological space). OK, that's a different question, then.

The answer is yes, by van Est; I don't have a good reference at hand, though, and I sincerely hope that someone will post an elementary proof.

Something along the following lines: Take a central extension $\mathbb R\to G'\to G$. The associated extension on the level of Lie algebras is trivial by assumption. Since $G$ is 1-connected, so is $G'$ and by the theory surrounding Lie's fundamental theorems, it follows that the Lie group extension had to be trivial to begin with. Again, missing adequate references here, sorry.

@Ben if we want to use van Est we would need to prove $\pi_3(G)=0$ though?

Dear @DonkyDang, the van Est map on $H^{p+1}$ is injective if $G$ is $p$-connected and that is enough here. We don't need van Est to be an isomorphism a priori.
